# How to rotate a 3D matrix along X,Y, or Z axial plane?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a 3D matrix with size DxHxW. I want to rotate it 90 degrees along the (1) X-axis, (2) Y-axis and (3) Z-axis. I just completed Y-axis. How can I do it with X and Z-axis? I am using python 2.7. Thanks all

```
rotate_90Y=numpy.rot90(input)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numpy.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html) has an `axes` argument. You can use it to rotate about all tree axes,

```
m = np.arange(8).reshape((2,2,2))
m1 = np.rot90(m, axes=(0,1))
m2 = np.rot90(m, axes=(1,2))
m3 = np.rot90(m, axes=(0,2))
```

(Since it's not clear what x,y,z axis are from the question, you need to decide for yourself, which one you need)

Comment: Great answer. I tried the axes before but i did not try your above setting